# InnerHTML does not outputs anchor elements but instead outputs current pg url. why?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, `links_container.innerHTML = links;` outputs `http://localhost/pagination/js-pagination.html#` instead of `<a href='#'>Page 1</a>`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pagination-links"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function createLinks() {
        var links_container = document.getElementsByClassName('pagination-links')[0];

for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var txt = document.createTextNode('Page ' + i + " ");
    link.setAttribute("href", "#");
    link.appendChild(txt);
    links_container.innerHTML = link;
  }
}
```

Can anybuddy explain. why

Comment: `link` is an object, an HTMLAnchorElement. `innerHTML` _must_ be a string, and HTMLAnchorElement is coerced to its `href` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML` is a string property and thus takes a string as value. Your `link` is an element object and because of this it's implicitly converted to a string with its `toString()` method, which does indeed return the URL.

Here are two ways you can fix this:

*Both of these solutions require you to clear the container **before** the for loop by running `links_container.innerHTML = ''`*

1. Append the element with `links_container.appendChild(link)`
2. Use the `outerHTML` of the element object: `links_container.innerHTML += link.outerHTML`

The first option is the more appropriate one as it inserts the DOM element you created into the DOM directly. The second option converts your DOM element to a string and then forces the browser to create a new DOM element from that HTML. If there had been any event listeners added to the element they would've been lost.

Comment: I really like the explanation but none of your solution worked. `links_container.innerHTML = '';` ouptuts just the last link i.e. `<a href=#>Page 4 </a>` instead of all page.Anything else??

Comment: @appu You have to run `links_container.innerHTML = ''` **before** the `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting innerHTML try calling appendChild. The `link` object is an element not an HTML string.

i.e. try changing:

```
links_container.innerHTML = links;
```

to

```
links_container.appendChild(link);
```

```js
function createLinks() {
  var links_container = document.getElementsByClassName('pagination-links')[0];

  // clear out previous html
  links_container.innerHTML = "";
  
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var txt = document.createTextNode('Page ' + i + " ");
    link.setAttribute("href", "#");
    link.appendChild(txt);
    // append link to container
    links_container.appendChild(link);
  }
}

createLinks();
```

```html
<div class="pagination-links"></div>
```

**Solution using innerHTML:**

```
links_container.innerHTML += link.outerHTML;
```

or

```
links_container.innerHTML += "<a href='#'>Page " + i + " </a>"
```

```js
function createLinks() {
  var links_container = document.getElementsByClassName('pagination-links')[0];

  // clear out previous html
  links_container.innerHTML = "";

  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var txt = document.createTextNode('Page ' + i + " ");
    link.setAttribute("href", "#");
    link.appendChild(txt);
    // add link
    links_container.innerHTML += link.outerHTML;
    
    // or you can use this instead of the above code
    //links_container.innerHTML += "<a href='#'>Page " + i + " </a>";
  }
}

createLinks();
```

```html
<div class="pagination-links"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, that was a typo, corrected it. Tried with `link` but still doesn't work. Anything else?

Comment: I've used appendChild, not innerHTML. Have you tried that?

Comment: Actually, my original code had `appendChild` but wanted to replace the existing elements rather than appending in the container therefore tried `innerHTML`, didn't work and thus resulted in this question.

Comment: @appu are you posting this question just for fun?

Comment: @aka, certainly not, I am learning vanilla JS and thus decided to build a pagination plugin and that's part of it.

Comment: Check the new solution.

Comment: gr8, Worked. but unfortunately, I've to mark  the more descriptive solution by Mikael Lennholm as it explains why it didn't work in the first place. Still thanks much for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
links_container.innerHTML = links;
```

with

```
links_container.innerHTML = link;
```

as you do not have any `links` variable there.

Comment: `links` was a typo, corrected it. Tried with `link` but still doesn't work.